# Circle Indicator not showing when replacing fragment with fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a view pager with circle indicator. Now my app has three fragments. First fragment show app logo, second fragment show some details about app and third fragment show that you are ready to use the app and then the MainActivity opened.
Now my previous problem was that i was unable to replace fragment as i wanted to show first fragment 5 seconds and then show next fragment. Now this problem is solved by this: `

```
private static int startPage = 5000;

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {          
            public void run() {    
                Fragment nextFrag= new LayoutTwo();
                getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFrag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
                }
            },     
        startPage);
```

This code will replace the first fragment with second but the problem is that when second fragment shows then circle indicator is not showing in it although it works before replacing the fragment.
My xml code for viewpager is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#E3564C"
android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/viewPager" />
```

Please Help why circle indicator is not showing after replacing first fragment with second?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by circle indicator? Like the progress bar or the dots on a ViewPager that tell you what page you are on?

Comment: Yes exactly sir the viewpage that tell me what page i am

Comment: Those dots aren't part of the actual ViewPager, they are an additional view, as far as I know. You won't get them without some extra work.  http://viewpagerindicator.com

Answer (score 0):

## Gradle

```
dependencies {
      compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
}
```

## Usage

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="#E3564C"
 android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/viewPager" />

    <me.relex.circleindicator.CircleIndicator
    android:id="@+id/indicator"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"/>
 </FrameLayout>
```

Add below code in main activity

## Main Activity

```
ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
CircleIndicator indicator = (CircleIndicator) view.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
viewpager.setAdapter(mPageAdapter);
indicator.setViewPager(viewpager);
```